# thumbs.db in windows 10 with emberjs

Tags: windows, ember.js

I've a project in Ember cli and I receive this error.

I can't run in windows cause thumbs.db file, I don't see any Thumbs.db file (Hidden folders are showed) and I run in administrator mode. Any clue?

Follow stack trace error:

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Filipe\Documents\GitHub\front-admin\dist\assets\images\Thumbs.db'
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'folderToProject\dist\assets\images\Thumbs.db'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1156:15)
    at TreeSync.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Filipe\Documents\GitHub\front-admin\node_modules\tree-sync\index.js:61:19)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at TreeSync.sync (C:\Users\Filipe\Documents\GitHub\front-admin\node_modules\tree-sync\index.js:50:14)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.copyToOutputPath (C:\Users\Filipe\Documents\GitHub\front-admin\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:124:10)
    at C:\Users\Filipe\Documents\GitHub\front-admin\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:132:21
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (C:\Users\Filipe\Documents\GitHub\front-admin\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:493:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (C:\Users\Filipe\Documents\GitHub\front-admin\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:505:17)
```

I already clean `temp` folder

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would try is to clear the `temp` directory in the application's folder.